# vba ignore my with statement

Tags: vba, with-statement

I was trying to use with...end with to specify a search range in vba in excel. i tried it in one file, it worked fine. Then I tried it in another, the with statement just got ignored. Below are the sample codes:

```
Sub feat_overlap_within_set()

Workbooks("stimulus_select_3.3.xlsm").Worksheets("feat_overlap within set 1").Activate

With Range("A2:A542")

Cells.Find(what:="hut").Activate

End With

End Sub
```

It is very simple, I have 2 cells containing the word "hut" in this worksheet, one in column A and the other in column B. I'm expecting to always find the one in column A, but instead, whenever I run this, it always point to the one in column B. And it worked just fine in another file created with the same version of excel (2016).

Comment: Why are you even using the With Block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making use of the "shortcutting" that is available with a `With` block.  A `With` block is designed primarily so that anywhere you type something starting with a `.` it is treated as `withObject.`.

```
Sub feat_overlap_within_set()

    Workbooks("stimulus_select_3.3.xlsm").Worksheets("feat_overlap within set 1").Activate

    With Range("A2:A542")

        .Cells.Find(what:="hut").Activate

    End With

End Sub
```

Adding that leading `.` is the critical thing.  Without it, you are just referring to `Cells`, which defaults to `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells`.

---

A better way of doing this, avoiding the `Activate` of the sheet, and changing the `Range.Cells.Find` to just a `Range.Find`, and checking whether a match was found, would be:

```
Sub feat_overlap_within_set()

    With Workbooks("stimulus_select_3.3.xlsm").Worksheets("feat_overlap within set 1").Range("A2:A542")
        Dim dest As Range
        Set dest = .Find(what:="hut")
        If dest Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Not found"
        Else
            Application.GoTo dest
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I was mainly just fixing the one missing `.` in the OP's code.  Perhaps I will do a "minimal" fix, and then a "better" fix.

Comment: Actually - the `Activate` is probably somewhat necessary.  But I will change it to an `Application.GoTo`.

Comment: Note, depending on whether the code is written in a worksheet's code-behind, `Cells` might be implicitly referring to `Me.Cells`, i.e. `WhateverThatSheetIs.Cells`...and anywhere else it's implicitly `ActiveSheet.Cells` - hence why these implicit `ActiveSheet` references are such annoying little evil things.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I despise people who put non-event code in worksheet code modules, so I will pretend that issue doesn't exist.  ;) :D